# Form spoofing and methods to solve it

Tags: php, html, forms, security

I'm trying to develop a form helper to prevent form spoofing. So i came up with this:

```
<form...>
<?=form::secure()?>
...
</form>
```

which stamps an hidden form with key '_token' with a token which is the md5 of the id of the user session (which is random and renewed after 1 week).
And then at the "action" url (from the form):

```
$token = (isset($_GET['_token'])) ? $_GET['_token'] : null;
$token = (is_null($token) and isset($_POST['_token'])) ? $_POST['_token'] : $token;
if (form::is_secure($token)) { // checks if the given token is equal to md5(user id)
    ...ok...
} else {
    ...error...
}
```

Does that prevent form spoofing or I am missing something? In case the user id expires in the exact moment when the user has just loaded the page and then submit its form, it will just print an error and he should submit the form again, but thats acceptable (it's rare).

I thought that the only thing that could go wrong here is if the potential attacker is able to get the user session id and then he can attach ?_token=id to it's request and give it to the user to browse, but at that point, if the attacker has the user session id it can do whatever he wants anyway.

Am I right? If not, how can I edit my code to accomplish my goal?

Comment: This doesn't really do much, most form bots will scrape all the form elements (including the hidden token) and pass them along with the submission.  If you dynamically added that token via an Ajax call, it would still be relatively easy to bypass but it would be a step that most bots don't take and a solution would have to be custom made for your site.  If someone is trying particularly hard to target your site in specific, there isn't much you can do to stop them.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, either they have the session id or they don't.  If they do, they can get the token as well. Gets me every time.

Comment: Just generate a random token and store it elsewhere to check it later, don't rely on user data because otherwise you may aswell just check whether the user is logged-in, it would not provide the additional layer of security that you are looking for. Also this is probably vulnerable to CSRF attacks.

Comment: Are you looking at targeted attack or just random form scraping? As the approach to negate both forms of spoofing can be quite different.

Comment: @iWantSimpleLife, what's the difference?

Comment: For general form scraping, you just need to put in some javascript that is difficult to scrape. Like insert a hidden field using javascript just before submitting. And the field is calculated using a hash of the current date and time. This is usually enough to defeat automated scraping. Targeted attacks are harder as the attacker will then customize their attacks based on that script. For targeted attacks, i usually rely on security that runs more on the server end.

Comment: Of cos the methods mentioned above are just examples. Will need to see your specific problem to propose a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are effectively reinventing the wheel, since the token requires a valid session to validate and thus only repeats the security layer of sessions while not adding anything extra. It is the equivalent of asking for someone to enter their password in and then asking for it again to be sure.  It may make everyone feel better, but if the password has been compromised, it only slows down the attack but doesn't prevent it.

This isn't to suggest that you shouldn't take these things seriously or to dismiss your attempts.  It is my philosophy that the content of the form (What is passed in via `GET` or `POST`) should be separated from other logic, such as security and calculations, and that the server should not consider user-supplied data as anything other than user-supplied data.  Ideally anyone could post anything to a forms action, and the server/controller will manage it  correctly and consistently.  The session is verified (security), the data is sanitized and then validated, and any values that are generated via JS when the user is actually using the web form is recalculated/verified.  The response, ideally, is generic enough, either a redirect or web-standard response, so that the requester, be it a web browser, command line user, or web service can interpret it.

If the above were the case, there would be less emphasis and concern of spoofing, more emphasis on enhancing security layers and validation layers separately, and, best of all, the back-end controller that did this well could easily be ported/reused as a web service backend.

Long story short:  Your solution isn't bad, it just isn't adding any real security as far as I can tell, and may even expose your back-end security logic.  If you have a specific spoofing concern/threat, it would be better to address that use case and work your way out rather than try to come up with a one-size-fits all solution right away.  It may turn out that your use cases have specific solutions/considerations that need to addressed at different points of the exchange.

Comment: Just for notice. The user id is stored every time. No matter if the user is logged in or not. It just serves the purpose to give an identification of the logical user browsing the page. My purpose is just to be sure that the user that is submitting the form is the one who loaded the html page of the form. I know (I read mostly) that are a lot of things that may happen (some hijacks the session, someone who get the user is... etc...) but that's not my concern for now. I'm assuming the the user id is a value that only the user browsing can have.

Comment: @Jeffrey - Your solution requires that the user first request the form then return/submit the form.  This limits the form on both ends as it does not allow the form to get posts via an API, and it forces you and the server to check to ensure that the assumption is met.  If you trust that the user id is only available to the user loading the form, why are you worried about spoofing?  If you think someone can spoof the plain text user id, you should focus on session integrity and validation on the backend, since anything that relies on the client response is vulnerable.

Comment: @Jeffrey - And sessions can be in place without any id management or user authentication. I mentioned passwords as an analogy, but the real point of my answer is that you *shouldn't* use id/password for what you are trying to achieve.  You should use it for general authentication and for authorization, and you should use sessions for ensuring that requests are not being spoofed.  Separation of concerns is not only easier to look at, it also lets each part get replaced/enhanced as needed.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get it. You say I shouldn't use id/passwords but I should use sessions. I'm using the id as a token for the session. I'm not using a login/logout method, I've never mentioned it. In concrete could you please make an example of what you mean by "use sessions for ensuring that requests are not being spoofed"? Thanks.

Comment: You should use id/passwords for authentication and authorization.  Sessions *can* use various unique info such as id and password to check for persistance/integrity, but sessions are not actually tied to anything other than the session id generated when the session is created.  What I have done in the past (and by no means do I think my roll-your-own attempts are infallible) is generate a random token when starting a session based on the user_id, password, requesting IP, and randomly-generated number. But hypothetically....

Comment: I could just create a token based on a random number and the requesting IP plus a random baseball statistic. A session only requires a server-side id mapped to some header value of the request.  Session integrity relies on something that can't changed or spoofed persisting between each request. IP address is fairly reliable. Using a nonce works (similar to what you've got in mind). But really what I am suggesting is that you should not worry if the form data request followed a request for the form but instead separate out session validation from form validation.

Comment: @Jeffrey - Last thing, for now.  Think of this way:  If little Bobby Tables sends a blind request to your form handler, but the data is valid, the concern shouldn't be whether he used your form to submit the data, but instead it should be whether the data is valid and, if he's using a session id, that he has legit use of the session.  Less emphasis on how someone got to the script and more emphasis on verifying session integrity.

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel. If you're not using a web framework, integrate one of the myriad libraries that add CSRF protection to your project such as [CSRF4PHP](https://github.com/foxbunny/CSRF4PHP/).

Your solution is close, but wouldn't work because the session ID would be scrapable by an attacker.

Comment: I haven't dug deep into the library you recommended, but I was wondering if it has policy options regarding Referrer header.  I find that method both incredibly annoying but also very effective for some of the simple yet easy XSS/RF maneuvers.

Comment: No, it doesn't. IMHO, the referrer header is so easy to spoof and so often disabled that it's somewhat useless anyway.