# Adding a string to a database

Tags: php, mysql, database, post

I'm trying to add a string to my database, where I have two columns: "id" and "image". The "id" column is supposed to increment and the "image" column should get a string. This is my phpcode:

```
<?php
$servername = "somename";
$username = "someusername";
$password = "somepssword";
$dbname = "somedatabase";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}



$image = $_POST["image"];


$sql = "INSERT INTO photos (image) VALUES ('$image')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

the html form:

```html
the html form:
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="phpcode.php">
    <input type="text" name="message" size="55">
    <input type="submit"name="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I use this app to send a post to the server: https://www.getpostman.com/ yet for some reason it only increments a value id and doesn't receive anything for image like here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IX51L.png)

Comment: Check that the image column in your database actually accepts VARCHAR and not id.

Comment: Try dumping, `var_dump($_REQUEST);die;` and check if you send any data with post request

Comment: you can't send image just using $_post you need $_FILES['image'];

Comment: `$image = $_FILES["image"]['name'];` and use `move_uploaded_file()` to upload it to destination folder

Comment: @ Mudassar he is not trying to send an image. Just wants to send a string value

Comment: if you use $_post[] than u need to send path

Comment: @MudassarSaiyed I'm sending a string that's why I use POST.

Comment: @PhpDev the column image is set to receive varchar of length 30

Comment: Do you get the success result on insert. If you don't try using $error = error_get_last();  echo $error['Message'];  This would give you the error message that might have occured

Comment: @PhpDev the message I get is "New record created successfully" which then adds a new incremented value for id, but without the image value

Comment: post your html form. I detect that your image field on the html form has no name attribute

Comment: <body>
<form method="post" action="phpcode.php">
<input type="text" name="message" size="55">
<input type="submit"name="submit" value="Send">
</form>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form method="post" action="phpcode.php">
 <input type="text" name="message" size="55"> 
<input type="submit"name="submit" value="Send"> 
</form>
```

As suspected, your name attribute field is wrong as it does not correspond to what you are trying to post .

Change to

```
    <form method="post" action="phpcode.php"> 
<input type="text" name="image" size="55"> 
<input type="submit"name="submit" value="Send">
 </form>
```

When submitting forms, PHP reads from your "name" attribute on your form. That is what you are posting to your controller file.

Comment: just a question, would it be possible to send the stirng without the form? I mean accessing directly: somedomain.com/phpcode.php

Comment: yes it is possible. I would not advise though, because that can be a security issue. This is called spoofing. You will need to secure your form so attackers would not be able to access and post funny variables to your form. You can have a secret token on your form, then verify if it is the same before saving to your database or anyother operations.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217476/form-spoofing-and-methods-to-solve-it

Comment: but assuming noone would try to spoof me how would I need to change the phpcode for it to receive a string and add it to the database?

Comment: Your form is fine. It would receive the string. Just make sure you post from the name attribute.

Comment: sorry for bothering but I have been also trying to send the string directly through phpcode and using the Postman application, I get this result: http://oi63.tinypic.com/dx2104.jpg and no string is added to the database just another id is incremented

Comment: it says success??

Comment: yes it says success, and in my database a new score is added with incremented id and empty image

Comment: And you have changed the name attribute in your form to "image"  and in php, $image = $_POST['image'];

Comment: I'm accesing directly the phpcode through Postman like that: mydomain.com/phpcode.php so I'm not using the html form for this, and yes I have $image = $_POST['image']